# php exec синхронно

Tags: php, exec

Подскажите в чем проблема:
Выполняю функцию через exec:

```
exec('ffmpeg -i '.$video.' -i '.$image.' -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=327:170:enable=\'between(t,'.$time1.','.$time2.')\'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy '.$output);
```

Этой функция выполняется около минуты, после нее вызываю отправку на почту с прикрепленным файлом, через php mailer, ниже этой функции.. В итоге очень часто бывает что письмо приходит с недорендеренным видео, т.е процесс exec еще не закончился, но функция ниже уже отправляет это видео, в чем может быть причина зарыта?

Comment: Не уверен что код выполняется именно так, как вы описали. Попробуйте выполнение функции анализировать (добавить вывод), возможно что-то выполняется не правильно.